# Send case attachments in visual force email template

Tags: apex, visualforce, service-cloud-console

Does anyone know if its possible to send case attachments using visualforce email template?
Currently, I have got a process builder that triggers an email related to case details once case is closed.
What i need is to include attachment in the case as well. is this possible using visual force ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include attachment in Visualforce email template.

Refer [Adding Attachments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_attachments.htm) and here is the sample code:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"
    relatedToType="Account"
    subject="Case report for Account: {!relatedTo.name}"
    replyTo="support@acme.com">

    <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
        <html>
            <body>
            <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
            <p>Attached is a list of cases related to {!relatedTo.name}.</p>
            <center>
                <apex:outputLink value="http://www.salesforce.com">
                    For more detailed information login to Salesforce.com
                </apex:outputLink>
            </center>
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>

    <messaging:attachment>
        <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">
            Case Number: {!cx.CaseNumber}
            Origin: {!cx.Origin}
            Creator Email: {!cx.Contact.email}
            Case Number: {!cx.Status}
        </apex:repeat> 
    </messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Salesforce blog explains on how case details can be added in attachment.What i really need is to add attachments that are associated to the case in visual-force email template.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am just looking for options, if anyone has implemented this requirement.